# replacing every pair in a list

Tags: haskell

I need a function (I named it `applyToEveryPair`) that works on lists, e.g. `[x0,x1,x2,x3,...]`, and uses a function
`f:: (a,a) -> [(a,a)]`. For every (distinct) pair `(xi,xj)`, `i/=j` of the list
I want all lists where `xi` is replaced by `yik` and `xj` is replaced by `yjk` where `xik` is the output of `f`.

This visualizes input and output

```
[a0, a1 ,a2 ,a3 ]  -- input to applyToEveryPair
  |   |
  |   |
  v   v
  f(a0, a1) =[(b0,b1),(c0,c1)]
  |   |
  v   v
[b0, b1, a2, a3]  -- to be included in output
[c0, c1, a2, a3]  -- to be included in output
   ...            -- more output
      |      |    -- now combine (a3,a1)
       \    /          
        \  /
         \/
         /\
        /  \
     f(a3, a1) = 
     [(d3, d1)]
        \  /
         \/
         /\
        /  \
       /    \
[a0, d1 ,a2 ,d3 ]  -- to be included in output
```

A use case would be to input a matrix and compute all resulting matrices for every (pairwise) line swap (`f` swaps lines), or, in my case, all possible move in a solitaire game from one stack of cards to another.

Long story, short code; This is how I do it so far:

```
applyToEveryPair :: ((a,a) -> [(a,a)]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
applyToEveryPair f (xs) = do i<-[0..length xs - 1]
                             j<-[0..length xs - 1]
                             guard (i /= j)
                             (x',y') <- f (xs !! i, xs !! j)
                             return . setList i x' . setList j y' $ xs

-- | setList n x xs replaces the nth element in xs by x                             
setList :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
setList = go 0 where
    go _ _ _ [] = []
    go i n x' (x:xs) | i == n    = x':xs
                     | otherwise = x:(go (i+1) n x' xs)
```

I think comonads are overkill here, and I have not understood Lenses (yet),
but have a vague feeling lenses apply here.

The solution I use feels not very haskellish. I want to know if this is a good way to write it, but especially the double use of `setList` looks terrible to me. How to speed up / beautify this code?

Comment: can you please provide example of `f :: (a,a) -> [(a,a)]`? how it can swap lines?

Comment: I think an example would be `return . swap`, when `a` is `[b]`.

Comment: I can't find a much better way to do this, but I would suggest using `Vector` instead of `[]`, as it has much better indexed access performance, and you wouldn't have to implement `setList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the lens library to remove the need for the `setList` function. The ix lens does this, giving read+write access to an element at an index. The type of this is:

```
ix :: Index m -> Traversal' m (IxValue m)
```

Or, for lists in particular:

```
ix :: Int-> Traversal' [a] a
```

Using the `.~` operator, the value of a lens can be set. So to remove need for the `setList` funtion, just use this:

```
applyToEveryPair2 :: ((a,a) -> [(a,a)]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
applyToEveryPair2 f (xs) = do i<-[0..length xs - 1]
                              j<-[0..length xs - 1]
                              guard (i /= j)
                              (x',y') <- f (xs !! i, xs !! j)
                              return . (ix i .~ x') . (ix j .~ y') $ xs
```

The other thing to notice about your code is it will call every pair of elements twice: eg it will call the supplied function with the item at index 2 and 5, then with the items at indexes 5 and 2. I'm not sure if this is intended.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a much nicer way to do this. However, on the performance side, you should definitely use a data structure with constant time random access, such as `Vector`. That would save you from writing the `setList` function.